# Zsh : command not found : ng on new Mac OS Catalina

Tags: angular, macos, angular-cli, zsh

I have download the new Mac OS Version Beta of Catalina. Now I should start to use Zsh. But when I want to run a Angular project in Atom, I receveid this message : "The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050."
I'am already using zsh Terminal but he doesn't found the ng commands.

Comment: Did you `npm install -g @angular/cli` ?

Comment: Have you tried raising this issue on Angular's Github?

Comment: @wentjun I am having the same issue, raised it an angulars github, they closed it and sent me here.  Apparently, they dont find it to be a bug lol.  Very helpful crowd over there  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15692#event-2667473843

Comment: Same here, as before, Angular github is useless place to ask about angular issues

Answer (score 18):

I also lost access to my commands after moving over to zsh following the Catalina upgrade. This fixed it for me: 
`source /Users/YOURUSERNAME/.bash_profile`

In order to get these changes to persist, I used oh-my-zsh (https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Install with curl: 
`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

Then modify your .zshrc file: 
`vi ~/.zshrc`

Underneath this line: `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

I simply added the command I mentioned at the start of the post:

`source /Users/YOURUSERNAME/.bash_profile`

Save the file as you normally would with vi/vim: `:wq`

Oh-my-zsh is also capable of a lot of cool things so be sure to read the documentation.

Comment: Much appreciated, that fixed it for me.  Just needed to restart terminal

Comment: No worries! I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: You on macOS, forget vi just type "open ~/.zshrc"

Comment: True - should have mentioned vi is a bit of a pain for those who aren't familiar.

Answer (score 3):

The [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) has to be installed on your machine.

install the `cli` by running the command : `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Yes, I'ts installed, but before the new version of Mac all was running well. Now I received this error : Your global Angular CLI version (8.0.4) is greater than your local
version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".

Comment: @Julianh1805 That's not an error its a warning, This is because of the angular-cli version specified in your projects package.json file is older than your global cli version. If you want to get rid of it, upgrade the project's angular version to match with the global veriosn of the cli (8.0.4 in your case)

Comment: I tried uninstalling, reinstalling and I did not even have a project so there is no way to complain about angular version in my project being older than global cli version.  I also linked it, no success.  Angular github is useless, they just closed it and refered to ask on so

Comment: I'm in the same situation, I tried every thing like you but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

check with node version you're on. Download here - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

For me I encountered same problem with version 8.

```
nvm ls
```

it should list node version - using version 13 of node - worked for me.

```
 nvm install 13
 npm install -g @angular/cli
```

should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you had previously gone through the steps by sindresorhus to "Install npm packages globally without sudo" for bash, do them again for zsh. https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md