# 'zsh: command not found: ng' in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal on Mac Catalina

Tags: angular, macos, visual-studio-code, zsh, macos-catalina

Newer Macs (`Catalina` OS in my case) now have the default `Z Shell` aka `zsh`. Using a Mac `zsh` terminal window, I've successfully installed `Angular 11.0.5` globally and created a project. I'm using `nvm 0.32.2` and `node 10.23.0`.

However, on opening `Visual Studio Code` and navigating to my project within VS Code's `integrated terminal`, I get this error message using any ng command, such as trying to generate a component:

`zsh: command not found: ng`

Does anyone know how to properly set up Visual Studio Code's `integrated terminal` to properly identify ng commands using `zsh`?

*I've found one possible work around here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58584109/6647188 but it uses third party tools which I'd like to avoid if possible. Is there no other known way to resolve this?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- From the menu navigate to: Settings -> Features -> Terminal
- Click in "Edit in settings.json”
- Add this line(key value) to the object:

  ```
  "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh"
  ```
- Close and relaunch Visual Code.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because that is what is needed. However without me doing anything, this was already present in the settings. Where I think I went wrong was that I had installed `Angular` globally, but had never closed and relaunched `Visual Studio Code`. I had opened a `New Window`, but this wasn't enough. A simple close and relaunch, as you stated, fixed things. Thank you!

Comment: @VictorMartinezCalvo : Could you explain, why this is supposed to help here? Actually, the shell invoked from Visual Code by the OP **is** already a zsh, as we can see from the wording of the error message he gets.

Comment: @user1934428 I should probably edit my question. The issue didn't have to do with `VS Code` using zshell and ng commands. The issue was (I believe) that after installing Angular globally, I needed to close and relaunch `VS Code` for it to recognize ng commands. @Victor Martinez Calvo did include this step in his answer, so I left this as the accepted answer.

Comment: This is now deprecated. New recommended way is `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"`

Answer (score 6):

Here is the settings that worked for me

```
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "tmux": {
      "icon": "terminal-tmux",
      "path": "tmux"
    },
    "zsh": {
      "path": "/bin/zsh"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

If this line does not work for you:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh"
```

Then try replacing "zsh" with "bash", like so:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. worked for me

```
alias ng="/Users/<user_name>/.npm-global/bin/ng"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48415572

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of vscode at 1.62 nothing worked until I tried setting the default profile using the instructions in their docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles

Not settings or commands needed just a few clicks on the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

New suggested way by vscode:

```
This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile 
in `#terminal.integrated.profiles.osx#` and setting its profile name as the default 
in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx#`. 

This will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that will change in the future.
```