# VScode integrated terminal is saying some commands are not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently using the latest version of VScode insiders edition for MacOS and commands like

`cmake ..`

return

`zsh: command not found: cmake`

but on an ordinary terminal, cmake works fine.

my aliases are also not working in the VScode integrated terminal. I am not sure what the issue is and any help is appreciated.

my current terminal settings

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65545504/zsh-command-not-found-ng-in-visual-studio-codes-integrated-terminal-on-mac

Comment: I tried the solution there but the error still persists.